# Why does only one chapter randomly start its content on the next page?

Tags: page-breaking, books

I'm writing a book using the `book` document class and, for whatever reason, one of my chapters has its contents start on the next page rather than the current page. I have no idea why this is; I looked for manual page breaks or anything that might be causing an issue to no avail. Each chapter is broken up into a `.tex` file that inputs other sub-chapter `.tex` files. So, I'm not really sure what to post as far as a MWE since this issue plagues exactly one chapter. Is there some arbitrary setting or command that I accidentally enabled that does this?

"Broken" chapter:

[image: Page-break chapter]

Example of a "correct" chapter:

[image: No page-break chapter]

Comment: The usual reason is a large unbreakable box which won't fit on the current page.

Comment: @JohnKormylo So, this was my first thought as well. Unfortunately, even after commenting everything out in the chapter (except for a single string of text), it still breaks the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was that, this chapter was being included via `\include` whereas the rest of my chapters used `\input`. Seems like this was a copy-paste error, but if anyone could explain why this causes a page break, I would appreciate it!

Comment: Give minimal example first.

Comment: include force a newpage

Comment: if you force a page break by using `\include` you get a page break. LaTeX does not use random number generators, the output is always a result of commands in the file. Your question could not be answered by anyone but you as it contains no information